# is there any way to create query which show count of repeated column with all rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database, count

I have a input like

```
column_1 |
    A    |
    B    | 
    B    |
    B    | 
    C    |
    C    |
```

output should be like

```
column_1 | count
    A    |    1
    B    |    3
    B    |    3 
    B    |    3
    C    |    2
    C    |    2
```

Comment: In the output also you need duplicate rows??

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a version in mysql that supports analytical functions, this is a breeze

```
select col1
      ,count(*) over(partition by col1 ) as cnt
  from t
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9d561d470418a794b4e22fc05c53a2cb

Answer (score 0):

This way:

```
SELECT A.column_1, B.Cnt 
FROM test A JOIN 
(SELECT column_1, COUNT(*) AS Cnt FROM test GROUP BY column_1) B 
ON A.column_1=B.column_1;
```

This fiddle : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/neoXeoVyyCwyDYTCBbHPGx/0